# concat two strings in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just like the title above: how to concatenate two strings in JQuery?

This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    serviceName = '<?=$_GET['services'] . ".php";?>';
    serviceID='<?= "#" .$_GET['services'];?>';
    serviceClass = '<?=$_GET['services'];?>';

    if (serviceName != "") {
        alert(serviceID);
        $('.main_content').load(serviceName);
        $(serviceID).addClass("it");
    }
});
```

As you can see in my above code, in variable name `serviceID`, I am concatenating `hashtag` and my `GET` value and I try to put it on ALERT and the result is correct, but when I assign it to `.addClass` it’s not working.

Any alternatives and solution is much appreciated.

Comment: concat with "+":    serviceName = '<?=$_GET[' + services +'] . ".php";?>';

Comment: This won't work, you're trying to return data from PHP to JavaScript. You'll need to make a call to your server (PHP) and return the value you need, then you can use this in JavaScript

Comment: Data from PHP to JavaScript should work fine

Comment: that code should work. try inserting `alert($(serviceID).length)`, to see if you did get the element, if it alert a number greater than 0.

Comment: the code is correct... I have pasted your code on php file... look at this.. http://www.iwebtool.com/code_viewer?domain=reigelgallarde.me%2Ftest.php%3Fservices%3Dreigel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you meant that the PHP code should be evaluated before arriving to the client, therefore your code syntax is correct, but check out the following looks cleaner and also not polluting the global JavaScript scope (that's what the var ... is for):

```
var serviceClass = '<?="{$_GET["services"]}";?>';
var serviceName = serviceClass+'.php';
var serviceId = '#'+serviceClass;
```

but, since your code syntax is correct, you should verify that you actually have an element with serviceId as the id when your are executing it

```
if (($(serviceId)||[]).length) {
    alert('your element with the id:'+serviceClass+' exists');
}
else {
    alert('your element with the id:'+serviceClass+' doesn\'t exists');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i hope this one solve the issue:

```
<script>
             $(document).ready(function(){              
                serviceName = '<? echo "./".$_GET["services"].".php";?>';
                serviceID   = '<? echo "#" .$_GET["services"];    ?>';
                serviceClass ='<? echo $_GET["services"];         ?>';

            console.log(serviceID);

                if(serviceName!=""){
                    alert(serviceID);
                    $('.main_content').load(serviceName);
                    $(serviceID).addClass("it");

                }
});
</script>
```

also check the console in your browser (firebug or chrome developer tools) to see the output ,fit your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Try as but not sure, My change is append `"#"` Id in jquery

```
<script>
             $(document).ready(function(){              
                serviceName = '<?=$_GET['services'] . ".php";?>';
                serviceID='<?= $_GET['services'];?>';
                serviceClass = '<?=$_GET['services'];?>';

                if(serviceName!=""){
                    alert(serviceID);
                    $('.main_content').load(serviceName);
                    $("#"+serviceID).addClass("it");

                }
});
</script>
```

Comment: For anyone else trying to see what the change was, the "#" has moved from the variable to the selector